# float right in DOM?

Tags: jquery

Struggling to float a div to the right of the webpage within JS.

The code within js is:

```
var options = {
            width: "360px",
            height: "240px",
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            border: '1px solid #ccc',
            borderRadius: 10,
            padding: 10,
            defaultLat: 51.500152,
            defaultLng: -0.126236
        };
```

I have tried float-right , any suggestions please

Comment: Can you post the HTML code you're using this on?

Comment: Wait... how about `float: 'right'` By the way, are you using some function to apply these style options to the HTML? It seems so obvious I can't post it as an answer, I figure I have misunderstood.  If it works tell me so I can post it as the answer  :D

Comment: float: right or its derivatives dont work in dom

Comment: check that whatever the element is that your trying to right align is not contained within a limited width element.
If it is in a div - that div needs to specify a width (100%) so any elements inside it to be able to align to the right of their parent...

Comment: Post three things, please: **1)** The relevant HTML **2)** A screencap of how it currently is. **3)** An description (or image if you can) of what you want it. That will help us understand your request better.

Answer (score 0):

If that's an object of JavaScript CSS properties to values, then appending this should work

```
styleFloat: "right", // IE
cssFloat: "right" // W3C
```

Edit: The jQuery [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) page gives us the clues we need

> Internet Explorer's DOM implementation
>   refers to the float property as
>   styleFloat, while W3C
>   standards-compliant browsers refer to
>   it as cssFloat.

Comment: @422 You're going to have to elaborate

Comment: Hi Phil, I can post you a link. But its on a dev site, so dont wish for it to be public. Tried via your blog, but no contact info.